# rewriting these vectors as a cross product

Tags: geometry

I am struggling to manipulate these vectors to the form I want

Is it possible to write $$ (\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{a} - 2\vec{b}))\vec{c} $$ in the form $ \vec{a} \times \vec{d} $  , where $\vec{d} $ depends on $\vec{b} $ and $ \vec{c} $ only ?

EDIT: i changed it to make sense (we had scalar  = vector before)

Comment: i've realised this doesnt quite make sense, as one is a vector and the other a scalar. let me check and correct it

Comment: No, because your expression is quadratic in $\vec a$, while the cross product is linear. For example, if $\vec b=0$, then you get $\lVert\vec a\rVert^2\vec c$.

Comment: @RahulNarain  thanks

Comment: @RahulNarain, please make your comment an answer, so we can get this out of the “unanswered” queue.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in comments:

> No, because your expression is quadratic in $\vec a$, while the cross product is linear. For example, if $\vec b=0$, then you get $\|\vec a\|^2 \vec c$. – Rahul Narain

I'll add that the linearity of an operator $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ is necessary, but not sufficient for it having the form $\vec a\mapsto \vec a\times \vec d$. The space of linear operators on $\mathbb R^3$ has dimension $3^2 =9 $. Those of the form  $\vec a\mapsto \vec a\times \vec d$ form a subspace of dimension $3$.

Some other necessary conditions are:

1. $T$ has rank $0$ or $2$.
2. $T^5$ is a scalar multiple of $T$.

I don't know if there's a neat and non-tautological necessary and sufficient condition.